# QML Image source is not updated while mouse is pressed

Tags: qt, qml, qquickwidget

I have ImageButton.qml which should change image when user holds the button.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Image {
    id: svg

    property string idleImage
    property string hoverImage

    signal clicked

    state: "idle"

    source: state === "idle" ? idleImage : hoverImage

    onSourceChanged: {
        console.log("source = " + source)
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton

        onPressedChanged: {
            svg.state = pressed ? "hover" : "idle"
        }

        onClicked: svg.clicked()
    }
}
```

But the image is not changed immediately. It's changed only when I hold the button for several seconds. When I press and release mouse button immediately I never see the hover image. onSourceChanged is executed immediately and outputs to console the right image source. This strange bug happens only when I use `QQuickWidget`. When I don't use widgets, but qml only everything works as expected.

Comment: You have to define `states` as well as `state`. having `state` only have no sense. btw definition of signal in your code is incorrect too.

Comment: I tried to define states. It doesn't help. It happens only when the moise button is down, when i release the button the image is updated.

Comment: I even tried to define a repeating  timer, which toggles image. It works well, but when i move cursor to the item and press mouse button, the timer stops working for several seconds. Its strange cause i removed mouse area in this experiment.

Comment: And I also tried to call update from cpp bridge after state is changed, and it doesn't help too.

Comment: Can you please post your entire code? With working and not working example. Your example works fine for me. There is no problem with your signal declaration or using `state` (even if `state` is indeed usually meant to be used with `states` and `PropertyChanges`).

Comment: @augre Does it work for you when you put qml inside QQuickWidget?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I can help but I need to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I am using `QOpenGLWidget` in the MainWindow. And I called update method in paintGL.

```
void Workspace::paintGL() {
    QOpenGLWidget::paintGL();
    workspaceDrawer.draw();
    update();
}
```

I replaced update call with a timer, running every 1000 / 60 milliseconds.
And the issue was gone. It's strange that it was reproduced only when a mouse button was pressed, otherwise everything was updated correctly.